# Running a bash script that contains sed commands produces no results and just hangs. Why?

Tags: bash, sed

I have the sample code and the desired output below

**Sample:**

```cpp
void function_patternWD1()
{
   some_code;
   some_code_patternWD3;
   some_code;
}
/*some_comments_patternWD2*/

void function_patternWD4()
{
   some_code;
   some_code_patternWD6;
   some_code;
}
/*some_comments_patternWD5*/
```

**Desired Output:**

```cpp
void function_patternWD1()
{
   some_code;
   new_line_of_code_1;     //after sed command
   some_code_patternWD3;
   some_code;
}
/*some_comments_patternWD2*/

void function_patternWD4()
{
   some_code;
   new_line_of_code_2;    //after sed command
   some_code_patternWD6;
   some_code;
}
/*some_comments_patternWD5*/
```

**What I've tried:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "fileName" ]; then
   sed -e'/patternWD1/,/patternWD2/{/patternWD3/i new_line_of_code_1;' -e '}'
       -e'/patternWD4/,/patternWD5/{/patternWD6/i new_line_of_code_2;' -e '}' < "$1"
fi
```

Initially, I had tried

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "fileName" ]; then
   sed -e'/patternWD1/,/patternWD2/{/patternWD3/i new_line_of_code_1;}' < "$1"
fi
```

But it wasn't working so I asked a question here and a contributor **corrected it** for me to

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "fileName" ]; then
   sed -e'/patternWD1/,/patternWD2/{/patternWD3/i new_line_of_code_1;' -e '}' < "$1"
fi
```

which works fine with the single command but when I use it like in **What I've Tried:**, the script doesn't seem to work as it hangs and I don't see any results.

Can someone please explain the syntax behind this particular command usage, and why my command didn't work but the other one did?

Comment: `bash` parses command with lines. You are running `sed -e ....` command without any input. Proabbly you want `sed -e... -e... -e... < "$1"` as a one long line.

Comment: do you get any output from `sed --version` ? Else post the output of `uname -srv`.  Good luck.

Comment: There's a backslash for line continuation missing after `-e '}'`.

Comment: Thank you @Kamil Cuk and @Jens. I could make it work by doing either of your suggestions. I still have a question though, what is the purpose of extra ````-e```` and single quotes around ````}````? Why can't it be this ````sed -e'/patterWD1/,/patternWD2/{/patternWD3/i new_line_of_code_1;}'```` ?

Comment: @TheVirtuoso I already explained it in my answer for your previous question, please read and let me know what is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people already commented, you are missing a backslash to tell bash that your command spans two lines.

If you put the closing brace directly after the semicolon, sed will interpret it as belonging to the string you want to insert. Therefore, you have to end the string by closing the expression and putting the closing brace into its own expression.

If you need to match the indentation of the surrounding code, you need to escape the first space to make sed realize that the string you want to insert is starting. In your case, where there are three spaces for indentation, put backslash and three spaces before `new_line_of_code`.

With these changes applied, the relevant lines are:

```sh
sed -e'/patternWD1/,/patternWD2/{/patternWD3/i \   new_line_of_code_1;' -e '}' \
    -e'/patternWD4/,/patternWD5/{/patternWD6/i \   new_line_of_code_2;' -e '}' <"$1"
```